# sequelize-auto please i need more explanation

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express, sequelize.js

I am new to node js and I generated the models using sequelize-auto
I am encountering this error when I follow the recommendation of this link   https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize-auto  . if you i need more explanation

please here are my codes

my controller

```
var jwtutils = require ('../util/jwt');
var db = require ('../routes/bd');
const multer = require ('multer');
var jwt = require ('jsonwebtoken'); 
const base64 = require ('node-base64-image');
const mime = require ('mime');
const base64Img = require ('base64-img');
var initModels = require("../models/init-models");
var models = initModels(sequelize);

exports.get_publication = function (req, res) {
  models.publications
  .findAll ({
    where: {
      $and: [
        {'$users.ID_USER$': '$publications.ID_USER$'},
        {'$publications.ID_QUARTIER$': '$quartiers.ID_QUARTIER$'},
        {'$publications.ID_PRODUIT$': '$produits.ID_PRODUIT$'},
        {'$publications.ID_TYPE_PUB$': '$type_pub.ID_TYPE_PUB$'},
        {'$publications.ID_TYPE$': '$type_produits.ID_TYPE$'},
        {'$publications.ID_PUBLICATION$': '$images_pub.ID_PUBLICATION$'},
      ],
    },
    include: [
      {
        model: users,
        required: false,
      },
      {
        model: pays,
        required: false,
      },
      {
        model: produits,
        required: false,
      },
      {
        model: type_pub,
        required: false,
      },
      {
        model: images_pub,
        required: false,
      },
    ],
  })
  .then (data_pub => {
    return res.json ({
      statut: true,
      data_pub: data_pub,
    });
  })
  .catch (function (err) {
    console.log (err);
  });
};
```

my models publications

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  return sequelize.define('publications', {
    ID_PUBLICATION: {
      autoIncrement: true,
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false,
      primaryKey: true
    },
    ID_PRODUIT: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false,
      references: {
        model: 'produits',
        key: 'ID_PRODUIT'
      }
    },
    ID_USER: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false,
      references: {
        model: 'users',
        key: 'ID_USER'
      }
    },
    ID_QUARTIER: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false,
      references: {
        model: 'quartiers',
        key: 'ID_QUARTIER'
      }
    },
    ID_TYPE_PUB: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false,
      references: {
        model: 'type_pub',
        key: 'ID_TYPE_PUB'
      }
    },
    CONTENU_PUB: {
      type: DataTypes.TEXT,
      allowNull: false
    },
    TITRE_PUB: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING(255),
      allowNull: false
    },
    PRIX_PRODUIT: {
      type: DataTypes.DECIMAL(11,0),
      allowNull: false
    },
    NOMBRE_PIECE: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false
    },
    SUPERFICIE: {
      type: DataTypes.DECIMAL(11,0),
      allowNull: false
    },
    ETAT_PUB: {
      type: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
      allowNull: false
    },
    DATE_PUB: {
      type: DataTypes.DATE(6),
      allowNull: false,
      defaultValue: "current_timestamp(6)"
    },
    DATE_MODIF_PUB: {
      type: DataTypes.DATE(6),
      allowNull: false,
      defaultValue: "current_timestamp(6)"
    }
  }, {
    sequelize,
    tableName: 'publications',
    timestamps: false,
    indexes: [
      {
        name: "PRIMARY",
        unique: true,
        using: "BTREE",
        fields: [
          { name: "ID_PUBLICATION" },
        ]
      },
      {
        name: "I_FK_PUBLICATIONS_PRODUITS",
        using: "BTREE",
        fields: [
          { name: "ID_PRODUIT" },
        ]
      },
      {
        name: "I_FK_PUBLICATIONS_USERS",
        using: "BTREE",
        fields: [
          { name: "ID_USER" },
        ]
      },
      {
        name: "I_FK_PUBLICATIONS_QUARTIERS",
        using: "BTREE",
        fields: [
          { name: "ID_QUARTIER" },
        ]
      },
      {
        name: "I_FK_PUBLICATIONS_TYPE_PUB",
        using: "BTREE",
        fields: [
          { name: "ID_TYPE_PUB" },
        ]
      },
    ]
  });
};
```

init-model file

```
var DataTypes = require("sequelize").DataTypes;
var _commentaires = require("./commentaires");
var _images_pub = require("./images_pub");
var _localite = require("./localite");
var _notifications = require("./notifications");
var _pays = require("./pays");
var _produits = require("./produits");
var _publications = require("./publications");
var _quartiers = require("./quartiers");
var _regions = require("./regions");
var _roles = require("./roles");
var _type_pub = require("./type_pub");
var _users = require("./users");

function initModels(sequelize) {
  var commentaires = _commentaires(sequelize, DataTypes);
  var images_pub = _images_pub(sequelize, DataTypes);
  var localite = _localite(sequelize, DataTypes);
  var notifications = _notifications(sequelize, DataTypes);
  var pays = _pays(sequelize, DataTypes);
  var produits = _produits(sequelize, DataTypes);
  var publications = _publications(sequelize, DataTypes);
  var quartiers = _quartiers(sequelize, DataTypes);
  var regions = _regions(sequelize, DataTypes);
  var roles = _roles(sequelize, DataTypes);
  var type_pub = _type_pub(sequelize, DataTypes);
  var users = _users(sequelize, DataTypes);

  quartiers.belongsTo(localite, { as: "ID_LOCALITE_localite", foreignKey: "ID_LOCALITE"});
  localite.hasMany(quartiers, { as: "quartiers", foreignKey: "ID_LOCALITE"});
  regions.belongsTo(pays, { as: "ID_PAYS_pay", foreignKey: "ID_PAYS"});
  pays.hasMany(regions, { as: "regions", foreignKey: "ID_PAYS"});
  publications.belongsTo(produits, { as: "ID_PRODUIT_produit", foreignKey: "ID_PRODUIT"});
  produits.hasMany(publications, { as: "publications", foreignKey: "ID_PRODUIT"});
  commentaires.belongsTo(publications, { as: "ID_PUBLICATION_publication", foreignKey: "ID_PUBLICATION"});
  publications.hasMany(commentaires, { as: "commentaires", foreignKey: "ID_PUBLICATION"});
  images_pub.belongsTo(publications, { as: "ID_PUBLICATION_publication", foreignKey: "ID_PUBLICATION"});
  publications.hasMany(images_pub, { as: "images_pubs", foreignKey: "ID_PUBLICATION"});
  notifications.belongsTo(publications, { as: "ID_PUBLICATION_publication", foreignKey: "ID_PUBLICATION"});
  publications.hasMany(notifications, { as: "notifications", foreignKey: "ID_PUBLICATION"});
  publications.belongsTo(quartiers, { as: "ID_QUARTIER_quartier", foreignKey: "ID_QUARTIER"});
  quartiers.hasMany(publications, { as: "publications", foreignKey: "ID_QUARTIER"});
  localite.belongsTo(regions, { as: "ID_REGION_region", foreignKey: "ID_REGION"});
  regions.hasMany(localite, { as: "localites", foreignKey: "ID_REGION"});
  users.belongsTo(roles, { as: "ID_ROLE_role", foreignKey: "ID_ROLE"});
  roles.hasMany(users, { as: "users", foreignKey: "ID_ROLE"});
  publications.belongsTo(type_pub, { as: "ID_TYPE_PUB_type_pub", foreignKey: "ID_TYPE_PUB"});
  type_pub.hasMany(publications, { as: "publications", foreignKey: "ID_TYPE_PUB"});
  commentaires.belongsTo(users, { as: "ID_USER_user", foreignKey: "ID_USER"});
  users.hasMany(commentaires, { as: "commentaires", foreignKey: "ID_USER"});
  notifications.belongsTo(users, { as: "ID_USER_user", foreignKey: "ID_USER"});
  users.hasMany(notifications, { as: "notifications", foreignKey: "ID_USER"});
  publications.belongsTo(users, { as: "ID_USER_user", foreignKey: "ID_USER"});
  users.hasMany(publications, { as: "publications", foreignKey: "ID_USER"});

  return {
    commentaires,
    images_pub,
    localite,
    notifications,
    pays,
    produits,
    publications,
    quartiers,
    regions,
    roles,
    type_pub,
    users,
  };
}
module.exports = initModels;
module.exports.initModels = initModels;
module.exports.default = initModels;
```

error

E:\Mes Cours\Mes projet\Projet nodeJS\ImmoMarket\Controllers\PubController.js:9
var models = initModels(sequelize);
^

ReferenceError: sequelize is not defined
at Object. (E:\Mes Cours\Mes projet\Projet nodeJS\ImmoMarket\Controllers\PubController.js:9:25)

Answer (score 0):

1. In your controller, before defining -

```
var models = initModels(sequelize)
```

you should first `require sequelize`:

```
const Sequelize = require("sequelize");
```

2. Then, create a `Sequelize` instance -

```
const sequelize = new Sequelize('database', 'username', 'password', {
  host: 'localhost',
  dialect: /* one of 'mysql' | 'mariadb' | 'postgres' | 'mssql' */
});
```

Refer the section - Connecting to a Database in the [docs](https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/getting-started/) for more.